# How to represent the member function of list iterator operation in C++?

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, iterator, derived-class

Operator overloading is implemented by member function templates, but how to represent the following operation?

```
std::list<int> iter;
iter++; // <-- this operation
```

Can that member function be represented as

`std::list<T>::iterator& std::list<T>::iterator::operator++(std::list<T>::iterator& iter)` ?

If the above is wrong, then what is the correct **full** representation?

Comment: You're calling it on a `std::list`. Whatever overload there is should take a `std::list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)